# Adding dynamically rows to a table

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

Based on Railscasts's Prawn episode, I would like to add rows like this :

```
def line_items
  move_down 20
  table line_item_rows do
    row(0).font_style = :bold
    columns(1..3).align = :right
    self.row_colors = ["DDDDDD", "FFFFFF"]
    self.header = true
  end
end

def line_item_rows
  [["Product", "Qty", "Unit Price", "Full Price"]] +
  @order.line_items.map do |item|
    [item.name, item.quantity, price(item.unit_price), price(item.full_price)]
  end
end
```

I would like to add row dynamically after "@order.line_items" rows after but I don't know how to do that, then I tried :

```
def line_item_rows
  [["Product", "Qty", "Unit Price", "Full Price"]] +
  @order.line_items.map do |item|
    [item.name, item.quantity, price(item.unit_price), price(item.full_price)]
  end

  @order.other_line_items.map do |item|
    [item.name, item.quantity, price(item.unit_price), price(item.full_price)]
  end
end
```

But of course it doesn't works. Do you know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easy :

```
data = data + 
  @order.other_line_items.map do |item|
    [item.name, item.quantity, price(item.unit_price), price(item.full_price)]
  end
```